# Hash sign in front of property name - CSS browser hack?

Tags: css

This is part of a css I'm working on:

```
.center-part-3 { #position: relative; #top: -50%; }
```

I have never seen that type of hash sign usage. What is it for?

Comment: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/csshacks/hash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theorically is a [hack for IE7](http://www.tutorialswire.com/css/css-hacks):

But here you have [a comprehensive list of browser which fails or pass that hack](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/csshacks/hash). IE is not in the list (neither in the list which pass or fails), but add other browsers to the fail list.

Answer (score 2):

As all CSS hacks, it abuses the fact that some browsers will use the rule and other will not. Here's [a little reference](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/csshacks/hash).